# How to preserve the order of method execution in iOS programming?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, camera, uilabel

So currently I am working on a camera app in iOS. In general, when "Capture" button is clicked on the screen, it will do the following:

1. Display `UILabel` "Saving.." on the screen
2. `[camManager captureStillImage] //capturing the image`
3. Remove `UILabel` "Saving.." from the screen

The problem was, the "Saving.." label never appear on the screen. But, when I remove step 3, the label will actually appear on the screen, but after capturing the image.

So based on my understanding, this was caused either because step 2 was executed too fast or by multithreading such that these steps are not guaranteed to execute in the order as I wrote them. Is this correct?

If so, how can I guarantee that this label appear right before capturing and disappear immediately after capturing?

---

### Code

```
- (IBAction)captureImage:(id)sender {

     [self showLabel];

     [manager captureMultipleImg];

     [self hideLabel];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're blocking the main thread.

The main thread is responsible for UI stuff. When you're doing a long operation like `[manager captureMultipleImg];` probably is, the UI will not get updated. You need to use multi-threading in cases like this.

You can use `GCD` here:

```
- (IBAction)captureImage:(id)sender {
    [self showLabel];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), 
    ^{
        [manager captureMultipleImg];

        // Dispatch back on main for UI stuff
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self hideLabel];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: PS. Be careful, UI can be drawn just from main thread. In any case, I recommend to use completion callback. Change ``-captureMultipleImg`` to ``-captureMultipleImageWithCompletionBlock:`` and execute compeltion block when all images were captured.

Comment: That why `[self hideLabel]` is dispatched back on the main queue

Comment: Yeah, I know. But you don't know what is inside ``-captureMultipleImg``

Comment: @Vytautas Oh that's what you mean.

Comment: Thanks very much @NSAddict!! This solved my problem as well as exposed  me to this multithreading in iOS. I should probably learn more about GCD and multithreading in iOS. Also thanks @Vytautas for the tips!